# Install RHadoop on 32-bit Ubuntu

Tags: r, hadoop, rhadoop

**Objective:** To install **RHadoop** on single system(not VM version)

**System Specification:** 32 bit processor, 2GB RAM, Windows 7 & Ubuntu 12.10

**Explanation:** I am trying to run Hadoop with R using `RHadoop` library. Since my system RAM is less so if I try running `Cloudera VM`, it becomes very slow. I have gone through some of the tutorials online like 
1. [Insalling RHadoop](http://girishkathalagiri.blogspot.in/2012/09/installing-r-in-hadoop-rhadoop.html)
2. [RHadoop on Amazon EC2](http://blog.snap-interactive.com/post/26090105961/how-to-set-up-hadoop)

But none of them have complete steps. I was able to install R v2.15.2 and Rstudio in Ubuntu. I also have cloned github repository for RHadoop.

Can anyone suggest some good tutorial to install RHadoop on **32-bit** system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately 32 bit is not supported and there are reports that it actually doesn't work because of details in the serialization code. There are some fixes in dev but we do not test on 32-bit so they may or may not work. Lastly we have a dedicated google group for RHadoop where we are trying to build a community. We are a small community so we can't afford to be dispersed over github, SO, FB, quora, .

Comment: so you want to say that there is no way I can use RHadoop on 32-bit system. If yes, then are there any other packages like RHadoop which gives the same sort of capabilities i.e. R+Hadoop?